# MAC usage in Tor

Tags: authentication

Does every packet Tor sends have a MAC tag concatenated onto the end of the packet paylod? If so, how do they avoid pocket size overflow? Or is the MAC for a whole stream of packets??

Answer (score 0):

From to the [Tor FAQ](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq#RemotePhysicalDeviceFingerprinting):

> Tor transports TCP streams, not IP packets, so we end up automatically
>   scrubbing a lot of the potential information leaks. Because Tor relays
>   use their own (new) IP and TCP headers at each hop, this information
>   isn't relayed from hop to hop.

The [Tor Control Protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt) goes into a lot more detail on what actually goes into the stream.

If you have specific questions for the Tor Developers, you can ask in StackExchange or join one of the official [mailing lists](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo) for a more direct interface.